# How I can to know if Google Maps starts loading tiles?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to show a "waiting sign" every single time when GMaps is loading tiles and as soon loading is done, i must hide the waiting sign.

**Easy way:** listen ***tilesloaded*** event (of course) but...   not always the event fires... and then **I don't know WHEN** take the waiting sign away ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can listen to the `idle`, which fires when the map becomes idle after panning or zooming, which should also means the map is finish loading.

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/map_events/map_events.html